# Regex for finding a phrase that isn't already updated

Tags: regex, vba, ms-word, negative-lookbehind

I'm looking for some assistance with Regex. I have a project in which I'm writing a VBA macro to update hundreds of thousands of documents by find/replacing a phrase. The Phrase is "Company Name" and needs to be "Company Name LLP". The issue is that with Find/Replace I cannot prevent "Company Name LLP" from becoming "Company Name LLP LLP" (two LLPs) if it was previously updated. My workaround is to find "LLP LLP" and replace with "LLP" however there's obviously a better way using Regex. I'd like a regex that finds all "Company Name" WHERE NOT already "Company Name LLP" (even better it would also exclude "Company Name, LLP" with a comma). Can anyone please assist me with building this Regex? TIA!

Comment: Use `Company Name(?!\s+LLP)`

Comment: Hi Wiktor, thank you for the quick reply! Is there a way to make it not case sensitive so it finds "company name" as well?

Comment: You may set case sensitivty on the regex object.

Comment: Got it! Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a  `(?!\s+LLP)` negative lookahead to avoid matching `Company Name` before 1+ whitespaces and an `LLC` word:

```
Company Name(?!\s+LLP)
```

If these are whole words, enclose with word boundaries:

```
\bCompany Name\b(?!\s+LLP\b)
```

To make the expression case insensitive, enable the case insensitive mode on the RegExp object.

Example:

```
Set myRegExp = New RegExp
myRegExp.IgnoreCase = True 'Here, case insensitive mode is ON
myRegExp.Global = True
myRegExp.Pattern = "\bCompany Name\b(?!\s+LLP\b)"
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm now trying to exclude "Company Name, LLP" (with a comma). I'm using "\bCompany & Name\b(?!\s+LLP|\, LLP\b)". Is this the best approach or is there a more elegant way? I'm very new to Regex here...

Lastly, is there a way to find "Company & Name" or "Company and Name"? I've tried: "\bCompany (&|and) Name\b" but the parenthesis in the middle are generating another match.

Comment: There is a better one, `(?!,?\s+LLP\b)`, and to match both `and` and `&`, use `(?:and|&)`. `\bCompany\s+(?:and|&)\s+Name\b(?!,?\s+LLP\b)`

Comment: Wiktor, you sir are awesome. This would have taken me ages to figure out. My final regex is:

\bCompany (?:and|&) Name\b(?!,?\s+LLP\b)

Thanks!